# How do I display the content of the void method java

Tags: java, methods, void

I just want my program to display the sorted arrays in the void method but instead it doesn't display the sorted array or anything at all, it just loop around. I try removing the if else statement in the do while but it changes nothing. Anyone who's willing to help. It would be very much appreciated.

````
public class ArraysSorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number of Students : ");
        int num = in .nextInt();
        int[] StudNum = new int[num];
        String[] StudName = new String[num];
        int[] StudGrade = new int[num];

        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            System.out.print("Student Number : ");
            StudNum[x] = in .nextInt(); in .nextLine();
            System.out.print("Student Name   : ");
            StudName[x] = in .nextLine();
            System.out.print("Student Grade  : ");
            StudGrade[x] = in .nextInt(); in .nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }
        String str;
        do {
            System.out.print("\nSort By ? [S]Student Number [G]Grade [V]View [E]Exit : ");
            str = in .nextLine();
            if (str.matches("[vV]")) // i try removing this but nothing happens 
            {
                SortByView(StudNum, StudName, StudGrade);
            } else if (str.matches("[sS]")) {
                SortByStudNumber(StudNum, StudName, StudGrade);
            } else if (str.matches("[Gg]")) {
                SortByGrade(StudNum, StudName, StudGrade);
            } else if (str.matches("[Ee]")) {
                break;
            }
        } while (!(TestInput(str)));


    } //end of main method

    public static void SortByView(int[] StudNum, String[] StudName, int[] StudGrade) {
        //Sort by view
        for (int x = 0; x < StudNum.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("\n" + StudNum[x] + " " + StudName[x] + " " + StudGrade[x]); // pls display this output      
        }
    }
    public static void SortByStudNumber(int[] StudNum, String[] StudName, int[] StudGrade) {
        //Sort by student number
        for (int x = 0; x < StudNum.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < StudNum.length - 1; x++) {
                if (StudNum[y] > StudNum[y + 1]) {
                    int temp = StudNum[y];
                    StudNum[y] = StudNum[y + 1];
                    StudNum[y + 1] = temp;

                    String temp1 = StudName[y];
                    StudName[y] = StudName[y + 1];
                    StudName[y + 1] = temp1;

                    int temp2 = StudGrade[y];
                    StudGrade[y] = StudGrade[y + 1];
                    StudGrade[y + 1] = temp2;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < StudNum.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("\n" + StudNum[x] + " " + StudName[x] + " " + StudGrade[x]); // pls display this output 
        }
    }
    public static void SortByGrade(int[] StudNum, String[] StudName, int[] StudGrade) {
        // sort by grade
        for (int x = 0; x < StudNum.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < StudNum.length - 1; x++) {
                if (StudGrade[y] > StudGrade[y + 1]) {
                    int temp = StudNum[y];
                    StudNum[y] = StudNum[y + 1];
                    StudNum[y + 1] = temp;

                    String temp1 = StudName[y];
                    StudName[y] = StudName[y + 1];
                    StudName[y + 1] = temp1;

                    int temp2 = StudGrade[y];
                    StudGrade[y] = StudGrade[y + 1];
                    StudGrade[y + 1] = temp2;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < StudNum.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("\n" + StudNum[x] + " " + StudName[x] + " " + StudGrade[x]); // pls display this output 
        }

    }
    public static boolean isExit(String input) {
        return input.matches("[eE]") && input.length() == 1;
    }
    public static boolean TestInput(String input) {
        return input.matches("[sSvVgGeE]") && input.length() == 1;
    }

} //end of class```
````

Comment: What do you input for the do while loop?

Comment: Can you provide some input for the code?

Comment: i try inputting string "S" and "s" or "E" and "e" but it just continue without displaying anything form void methods

Comment: Which method are you talking about? You have multiple methods that return nothing (that have a void return type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following loop increment is incorrect

```
 for(int y = 0 ; y < StudNum.length -1; x++)
```

After fixing it to

```
for(int y = 0 ; y < StudNum.length -1; y++)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Number of Students : 2
Student Number : 1
Student Name   : a
Student Grade  : 1

Student Number : 2
Student Name   : b
Student Grade  : 2


Sort By ? [S]Student Number [G]Grade [V]View [E]Exit : s

1 a 1
2 b 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like this should be closed as was caused by a typo. Take a look at one of your for loops:

```
// Sort by student number
for (int x = 0; x < StudNum.length; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < StudNum.length - 1; x++) { // <- Here you increment x instead of y

  }
}
```

You do the same thing in all of your iterations, you are incrementing `x` in your `y` for.